# Track time spent on site

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

i want to track time spent on my site by an authenticated user.

To do that i have put this code on my layout:

```
  function js_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss (param) {
        now = new Date(param);
      year = "" + now.getFullYear();
      month = "" + (now.getMonth() + 1); if (month.length == 1) { month = "0" + month; }
      day = "" + now.getDate(); if (day.length == 1) { day = "0" + day; }
      hour = "" + now.getHours(); if (hour.length == 1) { hour = "0" + hour; }
      minute = "" + now.getMinutes(); if (minute.length == 1) { minute = "0" + minute; }
      second = "" + now.getSeconds(); if (second.length == 1) { second = "0" + second; }
      return year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
    }
    var start;



    $(document).ready(function() {
       var d = new Date();
       start = d.getTime();
    });
    <% if current_user %>
      $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        var d = new Date();
        end = d.getTime();
        timeSpent = (end-start)/1000;
        page = window.location.toString();
        debut=js_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss(start);
        fin=js_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss(end);

        $.ajax('<%= users_time_path %>', {
          async: false,
          type: 'POST',
          data: {log_time:{start:debut, end: fin, timespent: timeSpent, page:page}},
          success: function(res,status) { },
          error: function (res, status) {
                console.log('Server error: '+ status);
          }
      });
      <% end %>

      });
```

But with this code if the user have two tab open i count twice the time.

Futhermore if the user leave this computer with the tab open and come back two day later, i will count more than 48h...

What should I do to avoid that ?

How can i do thaht on server side to avoid fake time by users ?

thanks

Comment: how about using google analytics for these kinds of tracking features

Comment: you can send a ping to your server when the tab blurs, which you can then treat the same as a tab close. other than that last page, total time is the sum of the time spent between page serves...

Comment: @dandavis I have added an answer below that does this natively via JS library for events like page blur/unload/pagehide events etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**timeonsite tracker**](https://saleemkce.github.io/timeonsite) for this that captures authenticated users natively along with following other benefits:

- Multi-tab time on site capture
- Authenticated/Anonymuos users
- Clean Time on page and Time on site for each pageview
- Support for all major web and mobile browsers including IPhone, Ipad, Safari or Opera
- Domain/page URL based time on site separation
- Single-page app time on site tracking and
  much more.

Easy to use since pure JS code. It's also found in **CDNjs** & **JSDeliver** for quick integration

Answer (score 0):

Call the Server every 1-5 minutes (ajax or something), in php you have a session and the ip from the client, you can use booth to track and identify the user.

some links:

- http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-id.php
- http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php

for your fake protection:

- http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

stop calling the server after 1 min without mousemove or something ...